# setResult doesn't call onActivityResult

Tags: android

I have two activities which starts the same sub-activity for result.
But in only one of them onActivityResult works.
Here are parts of my code

This is my first Activity. As you can see it calls NewCommentActivity in startActivityForResult and this part works fine

```
public class OfferActivity extends ListActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

...

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.offer_menu_comment:
            Intent commentIntent = new Intent(this, NewCommentActivity.class);
            commentIntent.putExtra(Offer.OFFER, offer);
            startActivityForResult(commentIntent, COMMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;

       ...

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case COMMENT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Integer commentCnt = offer.getCommentCnt() + 1;
                offer.setCommentCnt(commentCnt);
                commentButton.setText(getString(R.string.offer_comments, offer.getCommentCnt()));
            }
            break;
    }
}

...

}
```

Here is my second activity which calls NewCommentActivity too, but here onActivityResult is not called

```
public class CommentsActivity extends ListActivity{

...

 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        ...
        case COMMENT_ITEM_ID:
            Intent commentIntent = new Intent(this, NewCommentActivity.class);
            commentIntent.putExtra(Offer.OFFER, offer);
            startActivityForResult(commentIntent, COMMENT_REQUEST_CODE);
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case COMMENT_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Integer commentCnt = offer.getCommentCnt() + 1;
                offer.setCommentCnt(commentCnt);
                Comment comment = data.getParcelableExtra(Comment.COMMENT);
                commentImageListAdapter.addItemAtFront(comment);
            }
            break;
    }
}

...

}
```

And here is code for NewCommentActivity :

```
public class NewCommentActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
private static final String TAG = "Gift/NewCommentActivity";
private Offer offer;
private EditText editText;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.new_comment);
    offer = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(Offer.OFFER);

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.new_comment_text);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.new_comment_button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (editText.getText().length() > 0) {
        new AddCommentAsyncTask().execute(offer, editText.getText().toString());
    }
}

private class AddCommentAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Comment> {
    private String errorString;
    private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

    @Override
    protected Comment doInBackground(Object... objects) {
        Offer offer = (Offer) objects[0];
        String text = (String) objects[1];
        Comment comment = null;
        try {
            comment = ServiceContainer.getService().addComment(offer, text);
        } catch (OfferException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "exception in comment", e);
            int id;
            if ((id = e.getErrorStringId()) != -1) {
                errorString = getString(id);
            } else {
                errorString = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            }
            cancel(false);
        }
        return comment;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progressDialog = Utils.newSpinnerDialog(NewCommentActivity.this, R.string.sending);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = Utils.newAlertDialog(NewCommentActivity.this, errorString, true);
        builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.dialog_ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                dialogInterface.dismiss();
                new AddCommentAsyncTask().execute(offer, editText.getText().toString());
            }
        })
                .setNegativeButton(R.string.dialog_cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        setResult(RESULT_CANCELED);
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .create()
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Comment comment) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Comment.COMMENT, comment);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

And finally AndroidManifest for all activities:

```
    <activity android:name=".activity.OfferActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.CommentsActivity"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:label="@string/comment_activity_title"/>
    <activity android:name=".activity.NewCommentActivity"
              android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
              android:configChanges="orientation"
              android:label="@string/new_comment_activity_title"/>
</application>
```

Please help me. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is the value of COMMENT_REQUEST_CODE?

Comment: Doing debug enter in onActivityResult??

Comment: are you sure that u r not canceling result i.e. your result code is ok. Identify it by putting log or debug the code.

Comment: I've found the error: COMMENT_REQUEST_CODE was negative.